# Serial Communication in c# with a microcontroller

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I am simply trying to send "0" to my MCU, when the MCU receive this byte, it will send back another byte ("0" or 1" or "2" or "3"). The MCU receive the byte normally, since the code written for the MCU is waiting till I receive the byte. The problem is with the C#, it seems that it's missing the data from the MCU, because sometimes I got the data correctly but most of the time I got it wrong. 
Here is the code for the C#:

```
private void CheckConnPuf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //When Check Connected PUF button is clicked
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        int serialinput;
        serialPort1.WriteLine("0"); //send "0" to the MCU to receive back a byte
        while (serialPort1.BytesToRead < 0) ;//if there is no data in the buffer do nothing
            serialinput = serialPort1.ReadChar(); // receive the byte
        richTextBox1.Text = serialinput.ToString(); //print the received byte
        if (serialinput==48) { //if the byte is "0"
            comboBox2.Items.Add("R0_SPREAD"); 
        }
        else if (serialinput == 49) {//if the byte is "1"
            comboBox2.Items.Add("R0_COMP");
        }
        else if (serialinput == 50) {//if the byte is "2"
            comboBox2.Items.Add("ARBITER");
        }
        else if (serialinput == 51) {//if the byte is "3"
            comboBox2.Items.Add("SRAM_150X125");
        }

    }
```

Here is the C# form to make things clear :

[image]

I am not sure about The part in the code where I wait for the data to be available in the buffer and then I can read it. If it's not correct, what is the way to do it ?

Comment: The best way to read uart is to use the DataReceived Event.  Also I would add a "\n" to each message and then read to the return.

Comment: @jdweng: Thanks, I will try your advice.

Comment: Protocol violation.  You say you send *one* byte to the MCU but you are actually sending *more* bytes.  Unclear what the MCU does with bad data but probably nothing pretty.  Use Write() instead of WriteLine().